# ISAPI filter using C#

Tags: c#-3.0, isapi-redirect

Most of the article in web talking about using C++ for creating ISAPI filter dlls.  Is it possible to create an ISAPI filter using C# ?  My requirement is to catch few Request and Responses and process it further, including verifying the existing URL in database and redirecting.

Is it possible to achieve the same using C#? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can you  http handler to do that.Msdn have a good article"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=vs.85).aspx" .Hope it helps